# Is the acceleration of a falling object constant? Explain

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

My name is  kakari john
I come  from  wiawso

Comment: No it is not constant. But the surface of earth,  it can be approximated as such.

Comment: @jensenpaull if it reaches a terminal velocity, won't the net acceleration be a constant?

Comment: Including air resistance yes,  just gravitationally, no